# How to allow anonymous users inside ADFS protected app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, visual-studio-2015, adfs3.0

I have a forms app behind ADFS 3.0. I'd like to give users option to access a form anonymously as well (they just wont have pre-populated fields like logged-in users get).

Something like:

- Click [Friends]  button => redirect to `/myform?t=friends` => check auth => prepopulate form
- Click [Visitors] button => redirect to `/myform` => blank form

**Question**: I can create a project in Visual Studio, change authentication to Workplace account and use onprem ADFS. But how do I make /myform available for anonymous users as well? Cannot use `<location>` attribute in web.config since it's not recommended for MVC projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried the <location> option?
```

You could always have two controllers which you redirect to on button click, one decorated with [Authenticate] and one not.